# saving zip comment with rubyzip

Tags: ruby, zip

Trying to use rubyzip to add comments to a zip file that I'm otherwise not modifying at all.

```
zf = Zip::ZipFile.open 'Archive.zip'
zf.comment = "blah blah blah"
```

I've tried `zf.close` and `zf.commit` with no luck.  I'm reading through the docs, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Anybody done this before?

Comment: Rubyzip only updates the comment if the actual contents of the zip file changed, so the only workaround is @knut's answer below. I just fixed this bug and sent a pull request on GitHub: https://github.com/aussiegeek/rubyzip/pull/41

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to RubyZip 0.9.7 (released today), which fixes this bug.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it successfully with the following code:

```
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

zf = Zip::ZipFile.open 'Archive.zip', 'w'
zf.comment = "blah blah blah"

zf.get_output_stream("first.txt") { |f| f.puts "Hello from ZipFile" }
zf.close
```

I added at least one document to create the zip file. Without content, there is no zip file (a comment alone does not seem to be *content*).

You don't create the zip, you want to modify a zip-file.

This works also, but it changes also the zip-file:

```
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

zf = Zip::ZipFile.open 'Archive.zip'
zf.comment = "CHANGED COMMENT"
zf.get_output_stream("second.txt") { |f| f.puts "Hello from ZipFile" }

zf.close
```

Based on this, you may do the following:

```
require 'zip/zipfilesystem'

zf = Zip::ZipFile.open 'Archive.zip'
zf.comment = "CHANGED COMMENT"
zf.get_output_stream("second.txt") { |f| f.puts "Hello from ZipFile" }
zf.commit #write the data and change the commen
zf.remove("second.txt")  #remove the data again - the comment changed

zf.close
```

Comment: Not exactly what I want to do, but that works.  Until the gem is updated I can always add and remove to update the comment.  Thanks!